# Some breakpointed errors and form load event -detailed notes in code

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I apologize in advance. I had severe water damage in my apartment today and missed my VB class and professors office hours. She says I can still do this on my own, but it's proving difficult(5:30AM here). I really want to learn it(it is for extra credit), but it she said it will be beneficial for the exam. The example she provided for us isn't any help.

I will provide the attached form and code(which is mostly complete I hope). I've Been struggling all day as I'm new to this. Thanks for ANY help or guidance.

The **classes are supposed to be read only.**(Balance(need to save value dblBalance), intRate, Interest, intTrans)

****Methods needed**** : Calc interest, Withdraw, Deposit
The hint she gave was First, get the interest rate input. Should be in the form_load event
Form should

1) Allows Deposits

2) Allows Withdrawals

3) Calculate interest rate (dblInterestEarned = dblBalance*(dblIntRate/12))

4) Reports current number of transactions at any time - intTrans+=1.
and obviously exit

***Edit I just think I screwed up really bad and made it harder than it should have been. So tired I apologize. Just realized the procedures in the Form.vb Also when form loads input box for interest should pop up first*******

Form[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/frw6o.jpg

```
Public Class Class1
    'Create member variables for properties

    Private dblBalance As Double
    Private dblIntRate As Double
    Private dblInterest As Double
    Private intTrans As Integer
    Private dblMakeWithdrawal As Double
    Private dblMakeDeposit As Double
    Private dblInterestEarned As Double




    'Create property procedures
    Public Property Balance As Double
        Get
            Return dblBalance
        End Get

        Set(value As Double)
            dblBalance = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IntRate As Double
        Get
            Return dblIntRate
        End Get

        Set(value As Double)
            dblIntRate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property InterestTotal As Double
        Get
            Return InterestTotal
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            InterestTotal = value '''''''*expression recursively calls property interest total
        End Set
    End Property


    ''trying to 
    '''calculate the amount of interest for the current period, 
    ''' stores this value in the Interest property, and adds it to the Balance property.
    Public Sub addInterest(ByVal addInterest As Integer)
        dblInterestEarned = dblBalance * (dblIntRate / 12)
    End Sub


    ''trying to add deposit
    Public Sub addDeposit(ByVal addDeposit As Double)
        dblMakeDeposit += addDeposit

    End Sub

    '''''to withdraw
    Public Sub subtractWithdrawl(ByVal subtractWithdrawal As Double)
        If dblMakeWithdrawal >= subtractWith() Then
            dblMakeWithdrawal -= subtractWith()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No sufficient balance")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function subtractWith() As Double
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function




End Class


          Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim dblMakeWithdrawal As Double

    Private Sub btnDeposit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeposit.Click
        Dim dblMakeDeposit As Double


        '''''how to capture inputs from the form load??
        'Add Deposit
        dblMakeDeposit = CDbl(InputBox("Please enter deposit if you have any"))

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWithdraw.Click
        Dim dblBalance As Integer

        dblMakeWithdrawal = CDbl(InputBox("Please enter an amount to withdraw")
        If dblBalance <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Insufficient funs")
        End If
    End Sub





    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        '''This is where to put the input box when the form loads? so the read only 3D display boxes update on form?
    End Sub


    Private Sub GetData(objAccount As Account)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub


End Class




Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```